# Enable scl python27 for Apache cgi

Tags: apache, python-2.7, centos6

I have a .cgi script written in Python that requires python 2.7 but CentOS 6 does not have it. I installed through scl.

I created python27.sh under /etc/profile.d

```
#!/bin/bash

source /opt/rh/python27/enable
```

While this works for regular users, obviously the cgi script still calls /usr/bin/python. How can I make the cgi script call python27 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#!/usr/bin/scl enable python27 -- python
```